# Error al conectar a la base de datos en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu

Hola tengo un problema al intentar conectarme a la base de datos de mysql desde angular al hacer una migracion

```
php artisan migrate
```

me salta el siguiente error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name
>   = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

ya le di acceso con `grant on *.*` desde mysql pero el error persiste

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucione modificando la clave mediante

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

Comment: Genial, por favor no olvides cuando te sea posible por favor marcar tu aporte como aceptado para que los demás sepamos que ya lo solucionaste